# Code not working (Event Driven programming)

Tags: java

So I am working on the following exercise:

Create a circle and put it in a pane, when a user clicks inside the pane, display one of the following messages: if the user clicked somewhere inside the circle, print "inside the circle", else print "outside the circle".

The problem is that regardless of where I click, I get "inside the circle".

I know other ways to solve this problem, but I am wondering why my approach isn't working.

```
public class Exercise15_12 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Text text = new Text(30,10,"");

        Circle circle = new Circle(50);
        circle.setCenterX(100);
        circle.setCenterY(60);
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.getChildren().add(text);
        pane.getChildren().add(circle);

        pane.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            double x = e.getX();
            double y = e.getY();

            if ((x <= 150 || x >=50) && (y >= 10 || y <= 110)) {
                text.setText("inside the circle!");
            }
            else {
                text.setText("outside the circle");
            }       
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane,400,400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        pane.requestFocus();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at your logic:

```
if ((x <= 150 || x >=50) && (y >= 10 || y <= 110)) {
```

This will always be true:

x will always be either less than 150 or greater than 50 and
y will always be either greater than 10 or less than 110.

First Solution: use `&&` in place of `||`

But second issue: note that this will define a rectangle, not a circle, and for that you'll need to use a little geometry, using the equation of a circle.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `if` statement.

```
if ((x <= 150 || x >=50) && (y >= 10 || y <= 110))
```

The `||` (or) operator returns `true` if either or both of its operands are true. Now, think for a moment about the expressions you are using as operands: if `x <= 150` is `false`, `x` must be at least 150, but that will always mean that `x >= 50` will be `true`, because x > 150 > 50. Similarly, with the `y` expressions, any number cannot be both less than 10 and greater than 110, so `(y >= 10 || y <= 110)` will always be `true`. So, the code inside the `if` block is always executed, and never the `else` code. You probably meant to do this:

```
if ((x <= 150 && x >=50) && (y >= 10 && y <= 110))
```

By replacing the `||` (or) with `&&` (and) in both expressions, the entire `((x <= 150 && x >=50) && (y >= 10 && y <= 110))` will only evaluate to `true` if x is *between* 50 and 150 (both greater than or equal to 50 *and* less than or equal to 150) and y is between 10 and 110.

---

However, even that code won't correctly solve the exercise: notice that some points outside of the circle but inside the rectangle around the circle will result in `"inside the circle!"` when clicked. In order to more accurately capture the shape of a circle, you'll want to work from its [equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Equations) to develop a better inequality that determines when a point is inside the circle. For instance you could try the statement below (try to figure it out yourself before looking):

> `if (((x - 100) * (x - 100) + (y - 60) * (y - 60)) <= 50 * 50)`

Comment: Using the equation would result in: if( (x-100)*(x-100) + (y-60)*(y-60) < 50*50 )